# How to replace all newlines with paragraph marks in LibreOffice Write

Tags: replace, newline, libreoffice-writer, paragraph-marker

I've used LibreOffice for years. However, I do not tend to need to replace a newline with a paragraph very often. Every time I do, I go to the LibreOffice page with the regular expressions and work through it and take quite a bit of time to get it right.

Today, as I did a general search I find an idea on [Webrosis](https://webrosis.com/replace-paragraph-line-break-libreoffice-writer/) that makes it easy. Since I come to stackoverflow first when I do a search, I decide to pull together the Webrosis idea and the solution for this particular issue together here.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn on Formatting Marks (ctrl-F10)
- Press Enter and then copy the paragraph mark
- Open search and replace (ctrl-H)
- In the search box enter \n
- Under other options turn on regular expressions
- Press Find All
- Close the search box and all the newlines will be selected
- Press ctrl-v and the paragraph mark you copied will replace all the newlines